# how to query/get data from Datasource in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datasource

i am building a database application in vb.net and i started by adding a data source from the  DATA in the toolbar. my connection is good and it shows all my tables in the data source panel.

i also see new classes related to my database, like

```
sakilaDataSet
sakilaDataSet.customerDataTable
```

...
and so on.

how do i query and use these ? i googled a lot and i am not able to get this.

```
Dim cust As sakilaDataSet.customerDataTable = New sakilaDataSet.customerDataTable
        Dim row() As System.Data.DataRow = cust.Select("customer_id=5")
        MsgBox(row.Count)
```

My last try was with the above code, but the `row.count` always turns out to be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i wanted to achieve was not to use connection strings again. After adding the data source in VB.net, it makes Data Classes and Adapters, which i can use directly to access the database, as follows :

```
Dim staff As sakilaDataSet.customerDataTable = New sakilaDataSetTableAdapters.customerTableAdapter().GetData
Dim rows() As sakilaDataSet.customerRow = staff.Select("email='" + email.Text + "'")
```

Comment: you should use parameters

Answer (score 1):

You need to open a connextion to the DB. Here are some options:

You could use [EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx), which provides a nice way to access data and control it by mapping to entities (classes). For this, in VisualStudio create a ClassLibrary project, add an item ADO.NET Entity Data Model. This will open a wizard that will help you connect to the DB, map the objects in the DB to entities and access the entities by a reference to an entity context. The basics are easy.

Other option is to use an [OLEDB provider](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets12p4.html), which is a classic way to access DB. An [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/Database-ADO.net/ConnectiontoAccessDatabase.htm) to open an Access DB of employees:

```
Dim connString As String = "provider= microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; " & _
     "data source=Employee.mdb;"

  Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connString)

  Try
     conn.Open()
  Finally
     conn.Close()
     Console.WriteLine("Connection Closed")
  End Try
```

Visit http://www.connectionstrings.com/ to get a list of common connection string for many DB. Other useful links:

EntityFramework:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/net30/article.php/c15489

http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials

OLEDB:

http://oreilly.com/catalog/progvbdotnet/chapter/ch08.html

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets12p2ed.html

http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/net/database-programming-made-easy.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This website http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/begdbapp7.htm had a good tutorial where it talked about what happens when you use the data sources window and how to use it in your code after that.

I know it's an old question, but it was very high in Google results, and it was more of a "This is how you should have done it" answer instead of actually answering with what it seems like you asked